# Alternative to navigateCrossDomain (@microsoft/teams-js)

Tags: microsoft-teams

I just found out about [navigateCrossDomain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@microsoft/teams-js/microsoftteams?view=msteams-client-js-latest#navigatecrossdomain-string---status--boolean--reason---string-----void-) of the teams sdk but since it is deprecated and will not work in the future I am searching for an alternative or the correct way for my goal.

What I want to do: 
Having an app with a static (private) tab. The tab is just a static html page with a bunch of links to sharepoint pages. This links currently won't open in teams directly since the X-Frame-Options are set to sameorigin. But when the user clicks a link on the page and it starts the navigateCrossDomain function with the SharePoint url as parameter, it will work and the page will open in the teams tab correctly. Is there a better/future-proof way to achieve this?

Comment: Duplicate of this [github question](). Please let's use the github question asked by you to track this.https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-teams-library-js/issues/323